# How to taken push view object into next view in flex

Tags: apache-flex

My problem is that when I try to pass an object from the navigator.pushView(view, dataobject), I can't figure out how to access the dataobject from actionscript. I can access {dataobject.property} from MXML easily, but I want to set a variable in the new view to the passed dataobjects property.

Answer (score 0):

You have the passed object available in 'data' property. You can easily set your new local variable in activateHandler as:

```
var myVar:String = data.myPassedVar;
```